# Migrate SQS and SNS configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We have a few different AWS accounts and I am looking to migrate the SNS configuration from one AWS account to another. Is that possible to migrate?

Many thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not have a 'migrate' capability.

A best-practice is to deploy "infrastructure as code" using CloudFormation or Terraform. Then, when you wish to deploy the same infrastructure to a different AWS Account, simply use the same template to deploy it.

If you did not deploy your initial infrastructure via a template, you might want to use https://former2.com/ to create a template based on existing infrastructure. You can then use that template to deploy the same resources in a different AWS Account.